# How to listen to a "count" variable change and trigger actions depending on its value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, counter

I have a counter on a web page and I would like to change an element's style depending on the value of my count variable.

I found the .change action but can't figure how to make it work. It may be not a suited solution.

Could you help?

```js
var count = 0;
counter.innerHTML = count + "/30";


document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
count++;
counter.innerHTML = count + "/30";
}

  
$(count).change(function(){
  var x = document.getElementById("changed");
  if (count >= 5) {
    x.style.color = "red";
  }})
```

```html
<div id="counter">
  Counter
</div>
<div id="button">Click to add 1
</div>
<div id="changed">This must turn red when counter > 5
</div>
```

Comment: You don't quite need to listen for variable value change, as values are normally don't change by themselves, you may listen to ***events*** that trigger variable change - button clicks, in your case.

Comment: The `change` event is triggered by HTML Elements. There is no method to "watch" the change of a variable. You will have to check the variable in the `click` callback that you have created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the counter is only updated by your code, you can directly add the check after you increment the count.

```js
var count = 0;
counter.innerHTML = count + "/30";
var x = document.getElementById("changed");

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  count++;
  if (count >= 5) {
    x.style.color = "red";
  }
  counter.innerHTML = count + "/30";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">
  Counter
</div>
<div id="button">Click to add 1
</div>
<div id="changed">This must turn red when counter >= 5
</div>
```

If you are incrementing the counter in multiple places, you can use a `function` to encapsulate the updating and checking of the value.

```js
var count = 0;
counter.innerHTML = count + "/30";
var x = document.getElementById("changed");

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  updateCount(1);
  counter.innerHTML = count + "/30";
}

function updateCount(inc){
  count += inc;
  if (count >= 5) {
    x.style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">
  Counter
</div>
<div id="button">Click to add 1
</div>
<div id="changed">This must turn red when counter >= 5
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that would work thanks, but the thing is I have multiple buttons on the same page that add +1 to my counter, therefore my code would be quite messy with 30 times the same check.

I was hoping for a more "elegant" / optimized solution

Comment: @Naga You can extract the check into a function that you call every time you update the counter.

Comment: @Naga You could also create a function to increment the counter, in which you encapsulate the check.

Comment: That's good suggestions !
I need to work on it then, I am quite new to coding so I don't think of all solutions

Comment: Ok thank you Iota for your update, that seems to solve my issue well !

Comment: @Naga No problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you cannot "react" to variable changes (unless they're properties of an object, in which case you could define a setter that reacts in the way you need).

Instead, just check the variable in those places where they **are** changed:

```js
let count = 0;
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");
counter.textContent = count + "/30";

function incrementCount() {
  count++;
}

function updateCounter() {
  counter.textContent = count + "/30";
}

function checkCounterGreaterThanFour() {
  if (count >= 5) {
    document.getElementById("changed").style.color = "red";
  }
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', incrementCount);
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', updateCounter);
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', checkCounterGreaterThanFour);
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
<button type="button" id="button">Click to add 1</button>
<div id="changed">This must turn red when counter > 5</div>
```

Things I've changed on top of those mentioned:

- changed `var` to either `let` or `const`. `var` isn't used any more unless you need its very specifics
- changed `div#button` to a real `button` element for better semantics
- properly defined all variables using `document.getElementById`. I know all elements with a unique id are available as global variables in the browser, but code should never rely on that as any other part of the code could have modified/overwritten those
- changed `button.onclick = ...` to `button.addEventListener('click', ...`. Preferrably always use `addEventListener` which allows to add as many listeners as you want, whereas `onclick` property can always only reference one handler
- split the `click` into three functions for re-use. Event listeners, when the event occurs, will be run in the order they have been added by the code.

Comment: That's great, thank you for those details. It helps

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following jQuery example.

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#counter").html("Counter: " + ++count + "/30");
    if (count > 5) {
      $("#changed").css("color", "red");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">Counter</div>
<div id="button">Click to add 1</div>
<div id="changed">This must turn red when counter > 5</div>
```

If you prefer Native JS, consider the following.

```js
var count = 0;
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Counter: " + ++count + "/30";
  if (count > 5) {
    document.getElementById("changed").style.color = "red";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">Counter</div>
<div id="button">Click to add 1</div>
<div id="changed">This must turn red when counter > 5</div>
```

Each of these assigns a `click` event to the `button` element. Then it's a matter of examining the `count` variable each time the button is clicked and using a conditional statement to perform the change.

If you have many buttons, move the details to their own function so each button can call the function.

```
function updateCount(){
  $("#counter").html("Counter: " + ++count + "/30");
  if (count > 5) {
    $("#changed").css("color", "red");
  }
}
```

The `click` callback can just call this function from any button.

```
$("#button").click(updateCount);
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", updateCount);
```

Comment: Great, it's a similar solution to the one from iota. Thanks for helping